# jQuery Mobile Debug Page Redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm progmatically changing the page in my jQuery mobile application, on a click of button. This is the code I'm using:

```
 $("#paymentConfrim").click(function() {
   $( ".paymentDetailForm" ).submit(function( event ) {
   if(!validatePaymentDetailForm()){ // if false comes from validation
      return false;
  }
  else{
      // I'm using changePage instead of jQuery pagecontainer widget as I'm using older version of jQuery mobile
      $.mobile.changePage( "#submissionConfirmation", {} );
     return true;
   }
 });
```

The page is getting changed successfully, but after a second or fraction of a second, the application is returned to homepage. As the application is big, with lot of legacy code, I'm unable to determine what code is causing that page change. As it happens after few milliseconds, I suspect there is some `setTimeOut` function that is causing that.

Strangely though the page is changed to homepage, the URL remains the same as of `#submissionConfirmation` page i.e. `localhost/mypage.html#submissionConfirmation`

How can I debug and know exactly what JavaScript code is causing that redirection?

Comment: One strange observation, if after being redirected to homepage, I again go back to form page (where form fields are already pre-filled from last submission), and resubmit, the confirmation page stays there (no more redirection). However, if I then click the close button to go back to homepage, the homepage redirects me back to confirmation page again after few milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

The reload is caused by the form being submitted. You need to prevent the default form submission behaviour by calling `event.preventDefault()` as the first thing in your handler.

```
$(".paymentDetailForm").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Comment: Tried...no change in behavior. It still redirects to the same page after same time.